# wxPython manipulate GUI in same program

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, process, wxpython

I am trying to create a GUI with wxPython.  After I create the GUI I want the code to continue to execute, so I have tried to throw the app.MainLoop() onto a new thread.  This gives me issues.  Also when I try to change the background color for example, it freezes up the GUI.

```py
import wx
import threading
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process




class Display(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'here'
        self.app = wx.App(False)
        super(Display, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetTitle("Yo mama")
        self.Show(True)
        thread = Thread(target = self.app.MainLoop)
        thread.start()
        self.Close()

        
    def DisplayGUI(self):
        
        self.SetTitle("MyTitle")
        self.Show(True)

    def Changetitle(self):
        
        self.SetTitle("Title2")
       
display = Display(None)

# do stuff

display.ChangeTitle()

# do stuff
```

So basically I want to be able to run a GUI, and control it later on within my program (not through the GUI itself with events).  I plan on having pictures display at random times.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI's `MainLoop` needs to run in the main thread.  So do this, and if you want events at random times, you can use a timer, for example, [`wx.Timer`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer.html).

Using this approach, all the changes you mention (displaying pictures, changing the titles, colors, etc) should be straightforward.  Plus, you'll get a lot more control this way, where you can start and stop timers, change the interval, have multiple timers, setup timers that trigger each other, and many other options.

To learn more about wx.Timer, a good place to start is always the demo.  There's also a tutorial [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/), and a video [here](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1510200&fromSeriesID=151).

(I've heard that there are ways to run the [MainLoop in a separate thread](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MainLoopAsThread), but nothing you mention requires that, and it will be much, much easier to just use a timer.)

Comment: I will give this a shot and let you know how it goes

Comment: OK.  I suggest that even if it doesn't work quickly, you stick with it.  There's really no comparison to how much better using timers will work than the option of running the main GUI in a separate thread.  Also, I've edited my answer a bit to clarify a few things.